# python write 40 times loops results in text

Tags: python-2.7, nested-loops, streamwriter, overwrite

I wanna loop the following scripts for 40 times ,then write it into a txt file.However, I am the begginning user of Python, no idea how to do that,

```
print ('TIME           =            0.00 hours since 1999-06-30 14:00:00 +00:00')
print ('x_spw_eye      =     138.50')
print ('y_spw_eye      =       7.20')
print ('pdrop_spw_eye =         1000.00')

for i in range(1500):
    print " ".join('%8.1f' % 0 for j in range(16))
    print " ".join('%8.1f' % 0 for j in range(16))
    print " ".join('%8.1f' % 0 for j in range(4))
```

and also should change the space number of the parameter 'x_spw_eye', 'y_spw_eye','pdrop_spw_eye',

For example,

in the next loops , the head should be like,

```
TIME           =            6.00 hours since 1999-06-30 14:00:00 +00:00
x_spw_eye      =     138.10
y_spw_eye      =      12.50
pdrop_spw_eye =          985.00
```

Is there any idea what kind of clue should I follow with?

Thank you so much!!!

All the bests,
Li

Comment: You can make a program repeat a certain number of times by using a `for` loop. Also, what's a space number?

Comment: yes, thank you very much, I did it in for for loops. but how could I output the results, it really so big.Thank you !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got another script that meet the original requirement better, finally could write the results to a txt file,that is,

```
f = open ('test_2.txt','w')
for x in range (41):
    f.write ('TIME           =            0.00 hours since 1999-06-20 14:00:00 +00:00\n')
    f.write ('x_spw_eye      =     138.50\n')
    f.write ('y_spw_eye      =       7.20\n')
    f.write ('pdrop_spw_eye =         1000.00\n')


    for i in range(1500):

        for j in range (16):
            f.write ('%8.1f'% (0)),
        f.write ('%8.1f' % (0)+'\n')
        for j in range (16):    
            f.write ('%8.1f' % (0)),
        f.write ('%8.1f' % (0)+'\n')
        for j in range (4):
            f.write ('%8.1f' % (0))  
        f.write ('%8.1f' % (0)+'\n')


f.close()
```

This one is better than last one, which could write all the results into a txt file, otherwise this results really a huge file

Answer (score 0):

Based on Kevin's answer, I finish the loops as follows,

```
for x in range (41):
    print ('TIME           =            0.00 hours since 1999-06-20 14:00:00 +00:00')
    print ('x_spw_eye      =     138.50')
    print ('y_spw_eye      =       7.20')
    print ('pdrop_spw_eye =         1000.00')


    for i in range(1500):
        print " ".join('%8.1f' % 0 for j in range(16))
        print " ".join('%8.1f' % 0 for j in range(16))
        print " ".join('%8.1f' % 0 for j in range(4))
```

However, the head part and how to write the results out I haven't got the solution yet.

Thank you for Kevin's remind.

Bests,
Li